# How to round a double to the nearest highest vale within a predefined list?

Tags: c#, rounding

first question on here after looking around for a while and having no luck.
This part of the program's purpose is to round a value which is >= 1 and <10 to the next highest value in the list below. 
An example of the list that will be rounded is:

```
var preferredValuesList = new List<double> { 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6,  
                                             1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0,
                                             3.3, 3.6, 3.9, 4.3, 4.7, 5.1,
                                             5.6, 6.2, 6.8, 7.5, 8.2, 9.1};
```

For example for a value of 2.1 should be rounded up to 2.2. A value of 2.4 should stay at 2.4

My current method for doing this from another question on here is such as:

```
double preferredResistance = 
preferredValuesList.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(tempResistance - item)).First();
```

I've heard of using a loop for rounding instead but i'm fairly new and don't understand how i would do it.

thanks for any help you guys can give.

Comment: did you try Math.Round()?

Comment: What do you mean "the next highest value"? What would you expect 9.2 to return?

Comment: Also why aren't you happy with the method for doing it that you posted?

Comment: For your sample data, what should be returned for a value of 9.5 (which is greater than the greatest value in the list)? And will your input list always be in ascending sorted order?

Answer (score 4):

You can use linq for this query:

```
double value = 2.1;
double roundedValue = preferredValuesList.OrderBy(x=>x).FirstOrDefault(x=> x>= value);
```

What it does is returning the first value in `preferredValuesList` which is greater or equal to the unrounded value. Which is exactly what you want.

The `First` Method which you mentioned `Returns the first element in a sequence that satisfies a specified condition.`  (from the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050(v=vs.100).aspx)). where the criteria in this example is `x >= value`

The Method `FirstOrDefault` does the same, except that instead of throwing an exception if no element is found it will return the default value (0, in case of list of `double`).

**Note**: The `.OrderBy(x=>x)` is just for making sure that your list is ordered (i.e. not {3 ,7, 5,1,9} for example...)

Comment: This seems plausible, but I think we need confirmation on what a value of 9.5 should return for the sample data in the OP's question. This will return 0, which may or may not be what's wanted.

Comment: you guys think too much on this. he can just assign a default max value for the values above 9.1.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree with IsThatSo. Without any further information about the context of what the OP is trying to accomplish there is no "right answer". this gives him the tools to achieve what he wants with a bit tweaking for edge cases.

Comment: @IsThatSo If the OP wanted to return 9.5 for an input value of 9.5, that's easy - if he wanted to return 9.1 for an input value of 9.5, it becomes more fiddly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I respect your enthusiasm, but even the OP doesn't care as much as we do. paying too much attention to simple questions like this and not being able to get simple and short answers from the OP makes me itchy. just saying.

Answer (score 3):

This avoids the O(nlogn) sort:

```
double preferredResistance = tempResistance;
var greater = preferredValuesList.Where( item > tempResistance);
if (greater.Any())
    preferredResistance = greater.Min();
```

Comment: This of course depends on the size of `preferredValuesList`. If it is small, like in this example, O(nlogn) is still better than O(3n) that you are suggesting. Any way for these sizes it does not matter and for the general case, you are correct...

Answer (score 1):

**Since your list is ordered, you can do a BinarySearch, which is as efficient as it gets.**

If the value is there, it'll return it's index, meaning no rounding is needed in your case. Otherwise, it'll return the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is higher than your item.

In simpler words, if the returned value is positive, just stick to your number.
Otherwise, get the number on the list as shown below:

```
int index = preferredValuesList.BinarySearch(item);
double preferredResistance = index > 0 ? item : preferredValuesList.ElementAt(~index);
```

In case it's possible the item is higher than the maximum value on the list, one of the following security check should be used:

If you want the item to stay as it is:

```
int index = preferredValuesList.BinarySearch(item);
double preferredResistance = index > 0 || ~index >= preferredValuesList.Count ?
item : preferredValuesList.ElementAt(~index);
```

If you want the item to be rounded down to the maximum value on the list:

```
int index = preferredValuesList.BinarySearch(item);
double preferredResistance = index > 0 ? item :
preferredValuesList.ElementAt(Math.Min(~index, preferredValuesList.Count - 1));
```